# How do I get 14.04 LTS to join a Windows workgroup

Tags: windows, workgroup

I was able to access my home network with Win 7 laptops and XP desktops and this desktop before upgrade/update to an XP desktop with large, shared hard drive.  Now I can't see the computers on the network from the Ubuntu desktop.  Workgroup shows up under networks, but will not show computers but times out.